# Is it possible to create a macro to create consistent function declarations in C/C++?

Tags: c++, function, macros, c-preprocessor

Basically I want to create a macro say

```
DECLARE_FUNC(name, arg1)
```

which would define the name of the function and the name of the argument.

I had attempted to do the following but failed

```
#define DECLARE_FILTER_FUNC(fname, arg1) (PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr fname(PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr arg1))
```

Then I defined the function as such

```
DECLARE_FILTER_FUNC(filterStatOutlierRemoval, inputCloud)
{
    return inputCloud;
}
```

I am expecting it to expand to

```
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr orcFilterStatOutlierRemoval(PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr inputCloud)
{
    return inputCloud;
}
```

When I compile I get

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but what I want to do is declare a set of filter functions all with the same declarations so I can pass them around as function pointers for more generic functionality.

Comment: Why did you wrap the definition in parenthesis?

Comment: And you should view the preprocessor output before asking.

Comment: Yup I should have. Thanks for reminding me. I so rarely find the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the extra parentheses out of your macro.

```
#define DECLARE_FILTER_FUNC(fname, arg1) PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr fname(PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr arg1)
```